# Spark kills executor before completing the process

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a spark application which for frequent itemset.At first I get all the distinct items and then pair them up. 
The number of items is fairly large and I am using m4.Xlarge instance with 30 GB memory.

```
  l = l.map(lambda x:(x[1])).distinct()
  lbroadcast = spark.broadcast(l.collect())
  x = spark.parallelize(itertools.combinations(l.collect(),2)).filter(lambda x:randomTest(x,lbroadcast))
  print x.collect()
```

Job 3 at line 158 is x ,making pair and filtering the pairs which are in broadcast.The print statement in the end doesn't print anything.
The same code runs on local machine but not on EMR instance.
I think it might be an issue with RDD memory. All tuples are being stored in broadcast variable.

16/12/03 19:24:26 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 18.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool

16/12/03 19:24:26 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 18 (collect at /home/hadoop/t.py:158) finished in 0.971 s

16/12/03 19:24:26 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: collect at /home/hadoop/t.py:158, took 1.039357 s

16/12/03 19:24:28 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 7

16/12/03 19:24:28 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 7 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 8)

16/12/03 19:24:32 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 7.

16/12/03 19:24:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 7 (epoch 4)

16/12/03 19:24:32 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 7 from BlockManagerMaster.

Comment: how many nodes does your m4.Xlarge cluster have? As available memory to the cluster the master node can't have it's memory written to and additional nodes only allocate 16.5GBs per node to be written to memory (At least in my experience not sure if this can be overridden). Is it possible you are spilling over to the nodes disk by under estimating how much resources you need?

My first instinct would be to increase the amount of nodes you are trying to execute the code with, but that may be because it will be hard to tell what the problem is without being able to see all the logs.